# Creation form for nested ressource returns params error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters

I have a table Convocations 
it has a column date, a column time and a column subscription_id
My convocation/new.html looks like this

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-5">
        <%= form_tag subscription_convocations_path(@subscription) do %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag :date, "Date" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :date, nil, class: "form-control datepicker" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag :hour, "Heure de la convocation" %>
            <%= time_field_tag :hour, nil, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <%= submit_tag "Envoyer la convocation", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my controller action convocation#create looks like this :

```
 def create
    @convocation = @subscription.convocations.build(convocation_params)
    authorize @convocation
    @convocation.save
    @notification = Notification.new
    @notification.user = @subscription.user
    @notification.content = "Vous êtes convoqué à #{@convocation.subscription.tournament.name} le #{@convocation.date.strftime("le %d/%m/%Y")} à #{@convocation.hour.strftime(" à %Hh%M")}"
    @notification.save
    redirect_to tournament_subscriptions_path(@subscription.tournament)
  end
```

and finally my convocation_params :

```
def convocation_params
    if current_user.judge?
      params.require(:convocation).permit(:hour, :date)
    else
      params.require(:convocation).permit(:status)
    end
  end
```

when ever I fill my form in convocation/new.html - I get this error :

param is missing or the value is empty: convocation
and the highlighted line of code is this one in def `convocation_params`:

```
params.require(:convocation).permit(:hour, :date)
```

what's going wrong here ?

```
Logs :
Started POST "/subscriptions/25/convocations" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 17:32:03 +0100
Processing by ConvocationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cL8ESx4QRY+omoK9tuZczYzFBQZyZU81xTUQDT0kWJbNAVU2ruMF9gcxLLnBrNcNiHRjcvsjDwrM0n2lrSKJWg==", "date"=>"10/07/2015", "hour"=>"15:00", "commit"=>"Envoyer la convocation", "subscription_id"=>"25"}
  User Load (33.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Subscription Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 128ms
```

I initialize @subscription with a before_action :

```
class ConvocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_subscription, except: [:multiple_new, :multiple_create]
```

then

```
  def find_subscription
    if params[:subscription_id] != nil
      @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subscription_id])
    else
      @convocation = Convocation.find(params[:id])
    end

  end
```

My convocation/new method :

def new
    @convocation = @subscription.convocations.build
    authorize @convocation
  end

my routes related to convocations:

```
                  multiple_new POST     /tournaments/:tournament_id/convocations/multiple_new(.:format)    convocations#multiple_new
                multiple_create POST     /tournaments/:tournament_id/convocation/multiple_create(.:format)  convocations#multiple_create
      subscription_convocations POST     /subscriptions/:subscription_id/convocations(.:format)             convocations#create
   new_subscription_convocation GET      /subscriptions/:subscription_id/convocations/new(.:format)         convocations#new
           convocation_messages GET      /convocations/:convocation_id/messages(.:format)                   messages#index
                                POST     /convocations/:convocation_id/messages(.:format)                   messages#create
        new_convocation_message GET      /convocations/:convocation_id/messages/new(.:format)               messages#new
       edit_convocation_message GET      /convocations/:convocation_id/messages/:id/edit(.:format)          messages#edit
            convocation_message GET      /convocations/:convocation_id/messages/:id(.:format)               messages#show
                                PATCH    /convocations/:convocation_id/messages/:id(.:format)               messages#update
                                PUT      /convocations/:convocation_id/messages/:id(.:format)               messages#update
                                DELETE   /convocations/:convocation_id/messages/:id(.:format)               messages#destroy
               edit_convocation GET      /convocations/:id/edit(.:format)                                   convocations#edit
                    convocation PATCH    /convocations/:id(.:format)                                        convocations#update
                                PUT      /convocations/:id(.:format)                                        convocations#update
```

Comment: Can you post your server log generated while submitting the form?

Comment: How you are initialising `@subscription` in your controller? Please post the code.

Comment: Can you post your `new` method and `routes` file?

Comment: What happens when you change `@convocation = @subscription.convocations.build(convocation_params)` to `@convocation = Convocation.new(convocation_params)` with your original code.

Comment: nothing, it's exaxctly the same as before

Answer (score 1):

As per your generated params, this line

```
params.require(:convocation).permit(:hour, :date)
```

should be

```
params.permit(:hour, :date)
```

As stated [**here**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) under the ***require(key)*** section, it says

> Ensures that a parameter is present. If it's present, returns the
>   parameter at the given key, otherwise raises an
>   ActionController::ParameterMissing error.

Your params are generated without the ***convocation*** parameter, so is the error.

Comment: I did what you said but now I get another error :
```found unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, commit, subscription_id```

Comment: @DavidGeismar What happens when you change `params.permit(:hour, :date)` to `params.permit(:hour, :date, :utf8,  :_method, :authenticity_token, :subscription_id)`?

Comment: I get ```unknown attribute 'utf8' for Convocation.```